# MonoTouch / MonoDroid Service Layer incompatibilities?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, servicestack

We've begun to build `Cross platform Android/iOS apps`, having built exclusively in MonoTouch before. We're evaluating `MonoDroid`.

Our apps need to consume `JSON` and we'd like to use `ServiceStack`. Xamarin has a ServiceStack branch which we're using - https://github.com/xamarin/ServiceStack

We'd like to have a common project responsible for GETting and POSTing JSON. ServiceStack by Xamarin has `different DLLs for Android and iOS`. How do we have a `single project` and use ServiceStack to get at our JSON?

We're open to other options to get at JSON in a unified way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By and large, managed *.dll's compiled for MonoTouch that don't have a dependency on MonoTouch specific types are compatible with Mono for Android projects.

ServiceStack is a great example of this. I've personally used it for multiple projects across the Xamarin mobile framework offerings.

As a general rule I tend to encapsulate all invocation to my web services using a partial class with async methods, like `FooProjectRestClient`. And then if there ever is any sort of segmentation that needs to occur it can happen in a shared class using #if defs.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why there are MonoTouch **and** Mono for Android specific libraries is often because of the (smaller, Silverlight-like) profile available (e.g. things that depends on new FX4.0 features needs to be cut out). They are often the same code re-compiled with `SILVERLIGHT` (or `MONOTOUCH`, `MONODROID`) defined.

The reason for MonoTouch **only** specific librairies are generally because its environment (iOS devices) do not allow JIT'ing. So there's no code generation (e.g. `System.Reflection.Emit`) or dynamically (down)loading code... However it's often possible to provide (less performant) workarounds or skip a few features and keep a *special* version of the library for MonoTouch.

Now back to having a **single** shared assembly/project. The *special* MonoTouch assembly (generally the same code re-compiled with `MONOTOUCH` defined) is still a **valid** .NET assembly and **often** can be used in Mono for Android, Mono or .NET (once recompiled, even with `MONOTOUCH`). It's definitively not optimal but it's something you can try.

Another one is having the same projects (e.g. MyLib), across several solutions (e.g. MonoTouchApp, M4AndroidApp) and use special configurations (just like there's an iPhone|Debug one) to set different defines (e.g. `MONOTOUCH` on iPhone*|*). That can allow you to keep the best feature implementation in each platforms (e.g. in case the same feature is implemented differently).

I would try the later first (config), then sharing the MonoTouch special assembly and finally (if it really does not work) look for other alternatives.